# Sync tables between different database providers

Tags: .net, mysql, informix

I have 2 tables in 2 different databases, one is in a mysql server and one is in an informix server.

Using .net and odbc, is there a way to identify the differences of both tables and merge them?
so that both informix database and mysql database have the same data.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no integration between those 2 database. If it's just one shoot it's better export one of the tables and import into the other db and check.

The other way it's a row-by-row script using the primary keys.